# Can't get over #VALUE error in SUMIFS() where 2nd criteria being < given date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have made a home budget spreadsheet where I got a main calendar view and tabs for 'Standing Orders', 'Income' and 'Expenses'.

In the main view I use a forumla that returns sum of all payments at given date from a Standing Orders tab, but when adds to it End Date criteria as a second criteria it gives #VALUE error.

Could You please point me in the right direction? Maybe I should use different fomula / combination of formulas?

My formula:

```
=-(SUMIFS('Standing orders'!$D$4:$D$16,'Standing orders'!$B$4:$B$16,DAY(D4),'Standing orders'!$E$4:$E$12,"<"&D4))
```

Screenshots:
[image: Standing Orders Tab]
[image: Main View]

Comment: Without trying your formula I can see that you have used unequal sized ranges. That wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank You a lot, that's the thing 